# Algorithm for opposite vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

So I have an open area where 2 locations on the map are defined by points that are connected like so:
[image]

I basically want to write an algorithm that recognizes the direction of the arrow and generates an arrow in the exact opposite direction like so:
[image]

This is harder for me to figure out a solution to because the nodes (A, B, C) are just represented in the code by an ID and their GPS coordinates (Longitude, Latitude). Also, there are no arrows, I was just showing that for visual aid.

So basically I'm trying to find a way to generate that node C in the exact opposite direction of B, but the distance from A does not matter.

I'm not looking for full blown code just trying to brainstorm because I'm completely taken aback at this one.

Comment: High-school coordinate geometry. `v = B - A`, and `-v = A - B`. So you just need to subtract the coordinates of B from the coordinates of A and you're left with the coordinates of the antiparallel vector.

Comment: How do you infer the direction of arrow?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal `phi = arc tan((By - Ay) / (Bx - Ax))`

Comment: @H2CO3 my question was directed to OP.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I know, but that's how one computes the direction.

Comment: I mean how do you know you have to check A to B and not B to A?

Comment: @H2CO3 So if A is at (0,0) and B is at (1,0) then the arctan formula returns 0. So how exactly would I develop a point C that is at (-1,0) from that value?

Comment: @Richard Don't pay attention to the arctan formula, that was directed towards Abhishek Bansal. You can just use the "difference of coordinates" approach described in my very first comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 oh wow, you just create a vector from A to B which is going to be (1,0) in my case and then invert it to get (-1,0)....vectors...completely slipped my mind. Thanks!